# Pentaho Kettle conversion from String to Integer/Number error

Tags: csv, pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

I am new to Pentaho Kettle and I am trying to build a simple data transformation (filter, data conversion, etc). But I keep getting errors when reading my CSV data file (whether using CSV File Input or Text File Input).

The error is:

> ... couldn't convert String to number : non-numeric character found at
>   position 1 for value [ ]

What does this mean exactly and how do I handle it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it. The idea is similar to what @nsousa suggested, but I didn't use the Trim option because I tried it and it didn't work on my case.

What I did is specify that **if the value is a single space, it is set to null**. In the **Fields tab of the Text File Input, set the Null if column to space** .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That value looks like an empty space. Set the Format of the Integer field to # and set trim to both.